# How do I re-sync a read-only Google Drive local file with the version in the cloud?

Tags: google-drive

I'm getting the error "You only have permission to view this file, so your changes cannot be synced" because I accidentally edited a file I don't have access to. Since I don't need to gain access to it, I just want to re-sync to the unedited version.  In other words, is there a way for me to revert to the unedited version of the file on my end? The [help document](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2565956) on the topic just says to ask the owner of the file for permission to edit the file, but I don't want or need permission to edit the file. I just want the error to go away.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out!

When I had the box shown below checked, Google Drive warned me that some people may lose access to the file when my change was made and gave me the chance to undo it. This allowed me to revert back to the version in the cloud instead of on my local drive when I told Google to retry the sync.

[image: Google Drive Preferences > Advanced > System Settings > Show confirmation when removing items from shared folders]